# Parse String XML C# WPF

Tags: c#

I know this sort of question has been asked many times, but I haven't found anything that could solve my issue. Here's my scenario, I ftp a file from a server (an XML file) and receive it as a byte array which I then  decode into a string...below is my code for that. I now want to take this string and convert it into XML. I've tried lots of suggestions, e.g. using XDocument's Parse method and XmlDocument's LoadXml...see below, however I only see two nodes when I drill into either the XDocument or the XmlDocument object. Below is a sample of the xml that I get after converting the byte array.

I ultimately want to display this XML file on a datagrid, but since I only get two nodes when loading the xmls string into the XDocument/XmlDocument object I obviously don't get what I need.

Hope this makes sense. By the way, I'm relatively new to WPF so forgive me if this is a novice question. :)

```
string xmlStr = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(FTP.DownLoadFile(remoteFile));

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlStr);

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlStr);
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DataBaseUpdate version="CC03.11.003.5_v3">
    <inserttfsquery name="^-800*******" chargenumber="*********" length="0"
        translateddigits="866*******" objectclass="top|tfsquery" carrierid="0***"
        originatingdigits="*" expiration="" dialeddigits="800*******"
     />
<inserttfsquery name="^-855*******" chargenumber="*********" length="0"
        translateddigits="800*******" objectclass="top|tfsquery" carrierid="0***"
        originatingdigits="*" expiration="" dialeddigits="855*******"
     />

<inserttfsquery name="^-877*******" chargenumber="*********" length="0"
        translateddigits="877*******" objectclass="top|tfsquery" carrierid="0***"
        originatingdigits="*" expiration="" dialeddigits="877*******"
     />
</DataBaseUpdate>
```

**A bit more information:**
The XML that I need is captured correctly in the string after decoding the byte[]. At this point I need to "convert" the string into an XMl object of some sort. Once I have the XML object, I'd like to put it in a DataSet/DataTable so I can set the ItemSource to the gridView that's in my view,something like this:

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xmlStr)));
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = dataSet.Tables[0];
FileContentDgv.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

Comment: Would be nice if you could include the actual string, or what parsed XML you are expecting.

Comment: WPF is UI (just like WinForms is UI), so is not a correct tag. This should also be tagged with language.

Comment: But that is two nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution may help.

Use a WPF DataGrid and System.XML and System.XML.Serialization namespaces.

I saved the sample XML file you provided and loaded it as a byte array. Then I deserialized the XML to objects and used the list of inserttfsquery elements as the ItemsSource for the DataGrid, you don't need a dataset / table with WPF.

Here is the XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WPFXMLTest.MainWindow"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
   <Grid>
        <DataGrid Name="dataGrid"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace WPFXMLTest {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();            
            DataBaseUpdate dbUpdate = DataBaseUpdate.FromXML(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\temp\stackOverflow.xml"));
            if (dbUpdate != null) {
                this.dataGrid.ItemsSource = dbUpdate.InsertTFSQueryList;
            }
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="DataBaseUpdate")]
    public class DataBaseUpdate {

        public DataBaseUpdate() {

        }

        public static DataBaseUpdate FromXML(byte[] xmlBytes) {
            DataBaseUpdate dbUpdate = null;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(xmlBytes)) {                
                XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataBaseUpdate));
                dbUpdate = xs.Deserialize(ms) as DataBaseUpdate;
            }
            return dbUpdate;
        }

        [XmlElement(ElementName="inserttfsquery")]        
        public List<InsertTFSQuery> InsertTFSQueryList { get; set; }

    }

    public class InsertTFSQuery {

        public InsertTFSQuery() {

        }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "chargenumber")]
        public string Chargenumber { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "length")]
        public string Length { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "translateddigits")]
        public string Translateddigits { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "objectclass")]
        public string Objectclass { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "carrierid")]
        public string Carrierid { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "originatingdigits")]
        public string Originatingdigits { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "expiration")]
        public string Expiration { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "dialeddigits")]
        public string Dialeddigits { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks jiversion, your approach is much cleaner than dealing with a dataset/table. I went ahead and changed my implementation to what you suggest and it works. Before I changed it though I used this  var ReportElements = new List<XElement>(XDocument.Parse(XmlStr).Root.Elements("inserttfsquery"))); I then iterated over the collection and pulled out the values that I needed and stuck theM in a datatable. But like I said your solution worked much better and it's cleaner. Thanks again!!